# How to use gsub to remove one string from a line in R?

Tags: regex, r, dataframe, gsub

I have a dat file with data like this:

```
<Avg. Price>$103
<URL>http://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowUserReviews-g60878-d100506-r21086254-    
<Author>expressoparking
```

etc.

Here's the script I've made to identify each row with an

```
<Author>
```

tag, delete that tag, and lastly put the rest of that row into a single column in a data frame.

```
y <- read.delim("hotel_100506.dat")

author <- grep("<Author>*", y$v1)
data_author <- y[author,]
author2 <- gsub("<Author>", "", author)

dataPractice <- data.frame(data_author)
```

I know that my data_author variable has the correct data, but the data.frame method doesn't bring any of it over. What's going on here?

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++========================================================================

Okey doke - Here's the solution to putting the author tag line's information in a dataframe:

```
x <- read.delim("hotel_100505.dat", header = F)

Author <- grep("<Author>", x$V1)
data_Author <- x[Author,]
data_Author2 <- gsub("<Author>","",data_Author)

data <- data.frame(data_Author2)
```

Comment: nevermind - I solved my own problem. 

For one, the data.frame should be referring to new variable.
Secondly, I have a lower case "v" in "v1" when the document has it has "V1"

Comment: Please share your solution with the community, post as an answer below.

Comment: x <- read.delim("hotel_100505.dat", header = F)

    Author <- grep("<Author>", x$V1)
    data_Author <- x[Author,]
    data_Author2 <- gsub("<Author>","",data_Author)

    data <- data.frame(data_Author2)

Comment: Post as an answer, not as a comment, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The OP [offers this as the solution, in a comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28774594/how-to-use-gsub-to-remove-one-string-from-a-line-in-r#comment45828136_28774594):

```
x <- read.delim("hotel_100505.dat", header = F) 
Author <- grep("<Author>", x$V1) 
data_Author <- x[Author,] 
data_Author2 <- gsub("<Author>","",data_Author) 
data <- data.frame(data_Author2)
```